# How would I create a 2D array of strings of numbers in C?

Tags: arrays, c

I'm working an assignment and I'm relatively new to C. If I were to be given an input file like this:

```
25 08 10 15 10 
10 13 50 60 70 
10 10 15 00 90
00 05 07 80 12
10 05 60 70 88
```

How would I correctly store these in an array such that it's displayed like a 2D array or is that not possible in the way I'm thinking with C.

The code I have below is a function for converting the input file into a 2d array. Assuming that I have already other functions error checking if the file is in the correct format.

```
void createMatrix(FILE *fp) {
    int row = 5;
    int col = 5;
    char matrix[row][col];
    int i, j;
    char num[25];

    rewind(fp);
    for (i=0; i<row; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<col; j++) {
            fscanf(fp, "%s", name);
            bingoCard[i][j] = name;
        }
    }
}
```

This would work if it was integers I'm looking for but I need to preserve the 0's in front of numbers like
`00`
or `08`. I also later need to append to these numbers which is why I need to get them in an array in a string format. Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

I would then need to print the input file when making updates to it like this

```
25X 08 10 15 10 
10  13 50 60 70 
10  10 15 00 90
00  05 07 80 12
10  05 60 70 88
```

Comment: Look at `printf`'s format specifiers. Something like `%02d` would work to prefix a number with a 0. Keep in mind that how you store things in memory and how you display them don't need to be the same.

Comment: Is the input raw data or text?

Comment: @Lundin this is text data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make each element in the matrix a *string* (an array). E.g.

```
char matrix[row][col][10];
```

Then read into that string directly:

```
fscanf(fp, "%9s", matrix[i][j]);
```

---

But you could also create your matrix as a matrix of *integers* and then use `printf` formatting to include leading zeros:

```
int matrix[row][col];
// ...
fscanf(fp, "%d", &matrix[i][j]);
// ...
printf("%02d", matrix[i][j]);  // Prints leading zero if value is only a single digit
```